# How to find a nested quotation with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

> "Hello my name is "Joe" and I'm 13."

I want the regex to print out "Joe" only, can this be done?

Comment: This is a relatively simple problem in the land of regex, and can be solved in several different ways.  There are tons of regex tutorials out there, I would suggest going through one or more of them if you intend to use regex often (or even if you don't, just for your own learning experience).  [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html) is one, and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx) is another one...pretty much you can find a bunch on google just be searching for "regular expression tutorial" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression that will find a quoted string within another quoted string:

```
/\".*?\"(.*)\".*?\"/
```

http://rubular.com/r/L8dMtNZxP5

The interior quoted string will be in \1.

Now, if you want a more complex nesting structure, you'll need additional logic to account for that.  The linked site may help you generate any further logic.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide the platform you're using for this regex but here is one way using php:

```
$content='Hello my name is "Joe" and I\'m 13.';
preg_match('/"[^"]*"/', $content, $m);
print_r($m);
```

#### Update:

**As per the comment below here is the code that OP is probably looking for:**

```
$content='foo "Hello my name is "Joe" and I\'m 13." bar';
preg_match('/"[^"]*"([^"]*)"/', $content, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(3) "Joe"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question...he wants to find the quoted string within another quoted string, i.e. ("blah "bleh" blah"), not (blah "bleh" blah)

Comment: @devyndraen: Thanks for clarification, I have updated my answer as per your comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!"[^"]*)"([^"]+)"
```

Consider this string (with \ escaped quotes):
string test = "\"Hello my name is \"Joe\" and I'm 13.\"";

That expression will match `"Joe"` and the first capture will be `Joe`.  I couldn't tell which you were trying to get from your question.

In C#:

```
var match = Regex.Match(mystring,
            "(?<!\"[^\"]*)\"([^\"]+)\"",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Console.WriteLine(match.Value);            // "Joe"
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);  // Joe
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one fairly generic way to go about finding a single word inside double quotes, using Python's re module.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '''"Hello my name is "Joe" and I'm 13"'''
>>> re.compile('"\w+"').search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb73dc720>
>>> _.group()
'"Joe"'
```